# Intialiaze a cassandra Cluster using python

Tags: python, cassandra

I am initializing a cassandra cluster using this python  block of code :

```
cluster = Cluster(['172.31.29.49', '172.31.47.96'])
session = cluster.connect()
create_cassandra_table(session)
```

First I was putting this address 127.0.0.1 and I received this error :

```
    File "/home/ubuntu/snapshot.py", line 125, in <module>
    store_docker_checkpoints()
    File "/home/ubuntu/snapshot.py", line 94, in store_docker_checkpoints
    session = cluster.connect()
    File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1717, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
    File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1753, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
    File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1740, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
    File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3543, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection.connect
    File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3588, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._reconnect_internal
    cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1:9042':    ConnectionRefusedError(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

Then I changed the cluster with the two nodes' IPv4 private address. I am using a two-node cluster. Each node is an EC2 instance.
When I run the `nodetool status` everything is ok but when I run the script I get this error.

Comment: So I see the error when the address was 127.0.0.1, but it looks like you did not include the second error. Also, are you using authentication/authorization? You should be. In that case, you'd also want a way to pass-along the username and password.

Comment: the second error is the same as if I changed nothing. for authorization, I run the script as root.

Comment: From where you are running this python script, could you make sure you've connectivity to the appropriate CQL port by running `curl -v telnet://172.31.29.49:9042`. Apart from that, it would be interesting to see the output of either of these commands on one of the C* nodes --
`sudo lsof -nPi -sTCP:LISTEN` or `sudo netstat -tnlp`. If you're using non-standar port and others, you may need to use those appropriately like `cluster = Cluster(['172.31.29.49', '172.31.47.96'], port=..., ssl_context=...)` [API docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.29/api/cassandra/cluster/)

Comment: I tried sudo lsof -nPi -sTCP:LISTEN
I got
ubuntu@ip-172-31-47-96:~$ sudo lsof -nPi -sTCP:LISTEN
COMMAND   PID            USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd-r 322 systemd-resolve   14u  IPv4  16565      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
sshd      606            root    3u  IPv4  17307      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd      606            root    4u  IPv6  17309      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)

Comment: when I trie telnet 172.31.29.49 9042
I got:
ubuntu@ip-172-31-47-96:~$ telnet 172.31.29.49 9042
Trying 172.31.29.49...
Connected to 172.31.29.49.
Escape character is '^]'.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code (knowing that the IPs are private and I will not be able to see them):

```
cluster = Cluster(['172.31.29.49', '172.31.47.96'])
session = cluster.connect()
```

I get this message:

```
  File "/Users/aaron.ploetz/Documents/workspace/DS_Python_stuff/testCassandra.py", line 27, in <module>
    session = cluster.connect()
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1677, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1713, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1700, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3507, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection.connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3552, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._reconnect_internal
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'172.31.47.96:9042': OSError(None, "Tried connecting to [('172.31.47.96', 9042)]. Last error: timed out"), '172.31.29.49:9042': OSError(None, "Tried connecting to [('172.31.29.49', 9042)]. Last error: timed out")})
```

So it clearly knows the addresses that it's trying to connect to, and not defaulting to 127.0.0.1.

I am going to guess that either your changes to `snapshot.py` are not being saved, or the script you are trying to run doesn't have your changes.

Also, it's a much better idea to set IPs (and other runtime parameters) as environment variables or arguments on the command line. That way you aren't having to hard-code IP addresses.

Comment: I checked twice the changes are properly saved. I am still learning and don't know the level of changes I need to do following  your approach